# Internationalization at db level in Play framework

Tags: hibernate, jpa, internationalization, playframework

Is there a clean solution for multilingual fields in JPA?

I think about this db structure:

table product

```
+---------+--------------+-----+ 
| Field   | Type         | Key | 
+---------+--------------+-----+ 
| id      | bigint(20)   | PRI | 
| price   | varchar(255) |     | 
+---------+--------------+-----+
```

table product_lang

```
+------------------+--------------+-----+ 
| Field            | Type         | Key | 
+------------------+--------------+-----+ 
| id               | bigint(20)   | PRI | 
| lang             | varchar(3)   | PRI | 
| title            | varchar(255) |     | 
| description      | varchar(255) |     | 
+------------------+--------------+-----+
```

And this is the class I would like to use:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

  @Id
  public Long id;

  public Double price;

  public Locale lang;

  @Translateable
  public String title;

  @Translateable
  public String description;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure you can map one Entity to two tables the way you propose. Similar to what you want, you may store the translations as:

```
@CollectionOfElements
Map<String, String> titles;
```

where the key is the string for the Lang the user is browsing with and the value the title to show. This would create two tables in the database and allow for quick access to the translations.

Comment: This can indeed be my fallback solution, but how can I lookup every Product with title ilike '%book%' (when you have a locale). Can this only be done in hql? In Play you can use something like Product.find("byTitleLike", "%book%").fetch();

Comment: @Kris Pypen Play! allows for hql inside find. You can put the query in there

Comment: What about the fact that only one elements is needed most of the time?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, wrong solution. If you really want to have db internationalisation, I would rather create multiple databases rather than one big containing all the data.

Simply check langage in order to get right DB connection.

Comment: Using multiple databases would be a maintenance nightmare (even disregarding the extra level of complexity it adds)...

Comment: Well using a single database with many duplicates might be a nightmare for performance. The best solution stills is two instances of the applications and differents databases.

Comment: @Zenklys the performance impact won't be so big, specially using proper caching and indexing.

Comment: Let's settle this clear. If we are talkin about Internationalisation which means having different languages for a same product solutions given above are viable. If we are talking about localisation when products are different depending on langage, a multiple DB is IMO a better solution.